# useEffect does not see the state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make the functionality of adding products to the cart with updating the counter of the number of products and the total amount.

I can't understand why useEffect is triggered only when a new product is added to the cart. If I update the current quantity of the product that is already in the cart, then useEffect does not work.

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([])
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(cart.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.quantity, 0))
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(cart.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.price, 0))

  const addItemToCart = (id, foodName, url, price, quantity) => {
    if (cart.find(el => el.id === id)) {
      cart.map(el => {
        if (id === el.id) {
          const price = el.price / el.quantity
          el.quantity += 1
          el.price = price * el.quantity
        }
        return setCart(cart) // useEffect does not work
      })
    } else {
      setCart(() => [...cart, { id, foodName, url, price, quantity }]) // useEffect is triggered
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(cart.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.quantity, 0))
    setTotal(cart.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.price, 0))
  }, [cart])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this

```
 return setCart(cart) // useEffect does not work
```

write

```
      setCart(prevCart => prevCart.map(el => {
        if (id === el.id) {
          const price = el.price / el.quantity
          el.quantity += 1
          el.price = price * el.quantity
        }
        return el
      }))
```

Two issues with your code:

```
  cart.map(el => {
    if (id === el.id) {
      const price = el.price / el.quantity
      el.quantity += 1
      el.price = price * el.quantity
    }
```

This doesn't return anything. Cart.map doesn't mutate the list. So cart would just be the same I guess the objects would be mutated though, so `setCart([...cart])` would work after that.

And

```
return setCart(cart) // useEffect does not work
```

setCart can only take a copy of cart. This also wont do anything (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Fully updated code

```
  const addItemToCart = (id, foodName, url, price, quantity) => {
    if (cart.find(el => el.id === id)) {
      setCart(prevCart => prevCart.map(el => {
        if (id === el.id) {
          const price = el.price / el.quantity
          el.quantity += 1
          el.price = price * el.quantity
        }
        return el
      }))

    } else {
      setCart(() => [...cart, { id, foodName, url, price, quantity }]) // useEffect is triggered
    }
  }
```

Comment: "Fully updated code" is triggered twice. I can't understand why, but "return setCart([...cart])" - works correctly

Comment: setCart is called only once? Also, setCart([...cart]) just makes a deep copy of cart. It's better to shallow copy instead for performance reasons (e.g. memoizing it later on instead of rewriting every element)

Comment: Works a little weird. If I press the button several times, I get a double result. If I click on the button, then go to the cart (router), then go back to the product page and add this product again, then it works fine.